# Is there a possibility to get a list of all loaded modules in dojo 1.10/amd

Tags: module, dojo, amd

like the title says, I would like to have the information which modules are actually loaded at any time. Maybe there is a list like that in the debugger, but I can't find it. Or there is any other option to display it.

How to get that information?

Answer (score 0):

You can see all available module inside `require.cache`
So simply do:

```
console.log(require.cache)
```

To see them at debug time.

Comment: thank you! Gave me the right hint!
    console.log(require.modules);
is what I was looking for ;)